# Why isn't my AngularJS/Express/Socket.io app serving the socket.io.js file?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, socket.io, mean-stack

I have an Angular/NodeJS app, with Socket.io support added in for some real-time features.

I wanted to add MongoDB and PassportJS support so I have migrated to the [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) structure.

Suddenly, the Socket.io features don't work anymore.

One error I've found is that the client-side JS library served by Socket.io at `http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js` now returns the index.html page from my app instead.

That sounds like a routing problem, so here is my routing configurations:

**lib/routes.js (NodeJS):**

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    // Server API Routes
    app.get('/api/awesomeThings', api.awesomeThings);

    app.post('/api/users', users.create);
    app.put('/api/users', users.changePassword);
    app.get('/api/users/me', users.me);
    app.get('/api/users/:id', users.show);

    app.post('/api/session', session.login);
    app.del('/api/session', session.logout);

    // All other routes to use Angular routing in app/scripts/app.js
    app.get('/partials/*', index.partials);
    app.get('/*', middleware.setUserCookie, index.index);

    app.get('/:session', function(req, res) {
        res.render('views/index.html', {
            title: 'Weld Spark'
        });
    });

};
```

**app/scripts/app.js (AngularJS):**

```
angular.module('weld.common').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/main', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/main',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/login',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
        .when('/signup', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/signup',
            controller: 'SignupCtrl'
        })
        .when('/settings', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/settings',
            controller: 'SettingsCtrl',
            authenticate: true
        })
        .when('/:session', {
            templateUrl: 'views/ui-editor/editor.html',
            controller: 'weldEditorController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/my-project'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!'); // TODO: Test and figure out how this works in IE

    // Intercept 401s and 403s and redirect you to login
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', function($q, $location) {
        return {
            'responseError': function(response) {
                if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                    $location.path('/login');
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
                else {
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
            }
        };
    }]);

})
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {

    // Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
        if (next.authenticate && !Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    });

});
```

Any ideas why the socket.io route is broken?

**UPDATE: entire server.js:**

```
// Init Express framework and Socket.io
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    http = require('http'),
    socketio = require('socket.io');

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

// Application Config
var config = require('./lib/config/config');

// Connect to database
var db = mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);

// Bootstrap models
var modelsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'lib/models');
fs.readdirSync(modelsPath).forEach(function (file) {
  require(modelsPath + '/' + file);
});

// Populate empty database with sample data
require('./lib/config/dummydata');

// Passport Configuration
require('./lib/config/passport')();

// Init app and web server
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

// Init Socket.io server
var io = socketio.listen(server);
app.set('socket.io.log.level', process.env.SOCKET_IO_LOG_LEVEL || 1);
require('./lib/socket')(io, app.get('socket.io.log.level'));

// Heroku web socket workaround
//   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs
//   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku
io.configure(function() {
    io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
    io.set('polling duration', 10);
});

// Express settings
require('./lib/config/express')(app);

// Routing
require('./lib/routes')(app);

// Web: Start server
app.listen(config.port, function () {
  console.log('Express server running on http://localhost:%d in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
});

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: The routes file isn't particularly helpful here, as socket.io.js is served from socket.io itself. Can you post some of your code from app.js (or equivalent)--wherever you configure socket.io?

Comment: @distilledchaos Sure, just added that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Socket.io is listening to `server` with `var io = socketio.listen(server);`.

`app` is listening to the port, not `server`.

change

```
app.listen(config.port, function () {
  console.log('Express server running on http://localhost:%d in %s mode', config.port,
app.get('env'));
});
```

to

```
server.listen(config.port, function () {
  console.log('Express server running on http://localhost:%d in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
});
```

Comment: Friggin' amazing! Thank you! One word = all the difference. Thanks!