# Access Socket.IO from Express.js controller?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, mean-stack

I believe I have socket.io setup properly in the main file (server.js) of an Express app.  How do I access socket.io from a controller to emit an event as part of a controller action?

I tried the following based on a similar post, but I am getting an error saying that socket is not defined.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Similar post:
[Socket.io emit from Express controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736065/socket-io-emit-from-express-controllers)

server.js:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    http = require('http'),
    socketio = require('socket.io');

/**
 * Main application file
 */

// Set default node environment to development
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var config = require('./lib/config/config');
var db = mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);

// Bootstrap models
var modelsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'lib/models');
fs.readdirSync(modelsPath).forEach(function (file) {
  if (/(.*)\.(js$|coffee$)/.test(file)) {
    require(modelsPath + '/' + file);
  }
});

// Populate empty DB with sample data
require('./lib/config/dummydata');

// Passport Configuration
var passport = require('./lib/config/passport');

// Setup Express
var app = express();

// Setup socket.io
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketio.listen(server);


require('./lib/config/express')(app);
require('./lib/routes')(app);

// Start server
// Call listen on server instead of app to setup socket.io.  See this post:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173182/why-isnt-my-angularjs-express-socket-io-app-serving-the-socket-io-js-file/21175137#21175137
server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on %s:%d, in %s mode', config.ip, config.port, app.get('env'));
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('socket connected');
  socket.emit('message', {
    message: 'You are connected to the backend through the socket!'
  });
});

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

routes.js:

```
'use strict';

var api = require('./controllers/api'),
    index = require('./controllers'),
    users = require('./controllers/users'),
    items = require('./controllers/items'),
    session = require('./controllers/session'),
    middleware = require('./middleware');

/**
 * Application routes
 */
module.exports = function(app, socket) {

  app.route('/api/items')
    .get(items.index)
    .post(items.create(socket));

  // All undefined api routes should return a 404
  app.route('/api/*')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      res.send(404);
    });

  // All other routes to use Angular routing in app/scripts/app.js
  app.route('/partials/*')
    .get(index.partials);
  app.route('/*')
    .get( middleware.setUserCookie, index.index);
};
```

items.js (controller):

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Item = mongoose.model('Item');

exports.create = function(socket) {
  return function(req, res) {
    // write body of api request to mongodb
    socket.emit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you started the socket server?

Comment: I believe so.  When I start the application with 'grunt serve' I am seeing my console.log message 'socket connected' in my console.

Comment: First try to follow this tutorial then I hope you can make yourself: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socketio-and-expressjs--net-31708

Comment: How about reducing your example to something less than 3 pages of code?